# How to set a responsive footer using media queries | html - CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I'm having a footer issue which must be responsive by using media queries.

I would like to make it with a flex method but I can't find a way to get the requested result.

Also, I think the organization of my html could be better.

If you guys could check this out if would appreciate it. Thanks!

[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC96G.png)

[Responsive footer with 940px media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvCnb.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 1850px;
  font-family: "BenchNine", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

footer {
  padding: 1em;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.footer-link {
  color: #000;
}

.footer-link:hover {
  color: #999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
}
```

```html
<footer class="flex">
    <nav>
      <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav>
      <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="footer-menu">
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <picture>
      <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </picture>
  </footer>
```

Comment: So you want it to be responsive and re-flow to one column on smaller devices? Do you have specific break-points? And, may I ask where you got stuck?

Comment: Yes it's what I'm trying to do. The break point is 940px. I made the footer as you can see but I can't make the responsive. I've tried several ways but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

For example by using the percentage for the column width.

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  background-color: #ededed;
}
footer nav, footer picture {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  footer nav, footer picture {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Note that if you want more space for the picture, you can change the width of the columns, for example 3x nav 22% , and the picutre 34%

Comment: This example doesn't look like the responsive result I put in my post. It should be only one list. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: it doesn't have to actually be one list, you can just make it appear like it is one list. Adjust the css using media query to look like one list. Ex. remove the padding and margins so it appears like one list and set all the lists to width: 100% so they stack. If you want to actually make them one list there is no point but that's wayy too much JS you would need to actually get that done

Comment: g4rf4z, it is a basic example. Give a `footer li, footer a { display: block; }`to set a full width to the links within the space there is, meaning 25% on a large veiw and 100% (all items are stacked) on a small view less then or equal to 940px

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 1850px;
  font-family: "BenchNine", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

footer {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
footer > nav{flex-grow:1}

.footer-link {
  color: #000;
min-width: 190px;
    display: block;
}

.footer-link:hover {
  color: #999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
}
```

```html
<footer class="flex">
    <nav>
      <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav>
      <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="footer-menu">
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a class="footer-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <picture>
      <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </picture>
  </footer>
```